# C# TCPClient How to get bad address/offline server to fail faster

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to figure out how to give better feedback to the user when my client software fails to connect to a remote server.  I think there are a couple of scenarios that I would like to differentiate between:

1. Invalid/Offline server
2. Valid server but port is closed
3. Valid server but a different program is using the port
4. Successful connection

The issue I am having is that #1 takes over a minute to timeout.  #2 and #3 fail almost immediately.  Is there a way that I can get #1 to fail faster?

Comment: The problem is that some servers just really do take longer to reach. Forcing a timeout of, say, three seconds could trigger 'invalid/offline server' messages aren't actually true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a connection timeout

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31514/Implementation-of-Connecting-a-Socket-with-Timeout

Just make sure that you set the connection timeout value to one that's reasonable for servers you are trying to reach (if they sometimes take 5 seconds to reach, don't set it to 1 second).